# While running an application the error occurs, while debugging it doesn't

Tags: debugging

There is an issue which appears while running the application. It is not an Exception, but the desired UI change is not been implemented.

While debugging to find the code which should be changed to fix this problem, the UI changes can be seen correctly, To be specific, if we put one breakpoint in the class where it is called, and press the Continue in NetBeans, the problem occurs. But if we step over to the next lines and try to see the state at the end of the debug, the component seems to work perfectly.

How can these kind of issues be resolved?